# How could I differentiate 404 Error and 500 Error in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, exception

I'm building a website. I'm facing problem with throwing different errors like 404 and 500.

```
        try
        {
           //logic comes here
        }
        catch(HttpException he)
        {
            throw he;
        }
```

Now 404 and 500 both comes under HttpException. But there is some other custom logic for both types. How could I differentiate Both, so that I could write two catch blocks ?

Comment: If you are using C#6, you can use [exception filtering](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2015/04/09/c.net-little-wonders-exception-filtering-in-c-6.aspx). Otherwise, you must have one catch, and have an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming C# 6, you can use [exception filters](http://druss.co/2015/05/c-6-0-exception-filters-try-catch-when/) to split the handing up into different catch blocks depending on status code:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (HttpException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == 404)
{
    // ...
}
catch (HttpException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == 500)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
try
{
    //logic comes here
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    var code = ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode;
    if(code == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
        //some logic1
    }
    if(code == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    {
        //some logic2
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to write two catch blocks. How can I do?

Comment: I think there are not specific error types for 400 and 500 errors, so you should use the only one catch block and then process error depending on `StatusCode`, as shown at my answer.

Comment: Couldn't you use C#6 exception filters? http://druss.co/2015/05/c-6-0-exception-filters-try-catch-when/

Comment: Yes, I saw them, and roslyn can target .NET 4.5 so there's no problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpException.GetHttpCode() method to find whether it was 500 or 404.

more details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.gethttpcode(v=vs.110).aspx